# How to match user defined data type in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, varray

I have a user defined data type `CRM_IDS`:

```
create or replace TYPE CRM_IDS AS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR(32);
```

In my table `purecov_summary`, the data type of column `NAV_CRM_ID` is `CRM_IDS`:

```
CREATE TABLE "PE_REG"."PURECOV_SUMMARY"
(
    ...
    "NAV_CRM_ID" "PE_REG"."CRM_IDS" ,
    ...
)
```

When I select the nav_crm_id of the first line with:

```
select nav_crm_id 
from purecov_summary 
where rownum = 1
```

I can get `"PE_REG.CRM_IDS('10035005')"`.

But when I run:

```
select * 
from purecov_summary 
where nav_crm_id = PE_REG.CRM_IDS('10035005')
```

I get this error:

> **ORA-00932:** inconsistent datatypes: expected - got PE_REG.CRM_IDS
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 1 Column: 37

How can I select with `PE_REG.CRM_IDS` type?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use nested varray column (`nav_crm_id`) within `table` keyword as `table(nav_crm_id)`. So consider one of the following :

```
select p.* 
  from purecov_summary p 
 where exists (select column_value from table(p.nav_crm_id) where column_value = '10035005')
```

**or**

```
select p.*
  from purecov_summary p
  join table(p.nav_crm_id) c
    on c.column_value = '10035005';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=23a253670e97cdf671fd7206c27e9372)</kbd>